# Nginx could not open mime.types . What changes are required?

Tags: types, nginx, mime

I use the following to run Nginx :

```
sudo /usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.2.8/bin/nginx -c /usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.2.8/nginx.conf
```

It shoots out a error :

```
nginx: [emerg] open() "/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.2.8/mime.types" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.2.8/nginx.conf:17
```

What is need for this to work ?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have `mime.types` file at `/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.2.8/`.

Change 17 line at your `/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.2.8/nginx.conf` to refer the right file path.

```
include /usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.2.8/mime.types;
```

to

```
include /usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.2.8/conf/mime.types;
```

`mime.types` file usually located at `conf/` directory, if not, you could find it using `locate mime.types' command.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I kind of figured that and simply asked nginx to run the that specified conf file using -c

Comment: even when not using homebrew, this answer correctly identifies the location of the *mime.types* file within the *.../conf* dir. worked like a charm.